# Overwrite values in a dataframe with values from other dataframe in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, merge

I have a two dataframes. One with a coordinates of sites, the other with with connections between them. 
For example:

df1:

```
SITE_ID     LAT       LON
101       23.4244   31.5356
102       45.0090   14.2424
103       35.3444   19.4242
104       42.0000   18.0002
```

df2

```
SITE_ID  FIRST  SECOND  THIRD
101       102    104     NaN 
102       103    NaN     NaN
103       104    NaN     NaN
104       NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Now I wanna to change all value(in all columns) in df2 with coordinates from df1. 
Desired output:

```
 SITE_ID              FIRST               SECOND       THIRD
23.4244 31.5356    45.0090 14.2424   42.0000 18.0002   NaN 
45.0090 14.2424    35.3444 19.4242          NaN        NaN
35.3444 19.4242    42.0000 18.0002          NaN        NaN
42.0000 18.0002        NaN                  NaN        NaN
```

It's ok to have a little variation on this white comma or putting in lists. Later I'm gonna transform this to json and use it with javascript google maps api..
To be honest, I don't have so much idea, I've tried with transforming into dict, or overwrite while merging, but nothing really works till the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way, create  mapping from `df1` and replace values in `df2`

```
In [1120]: mapping = df1.set_index('SITE_ID').astype(str).apply(' '.join, axis=1).to_dict()

In [1121]: mapping
Out[1121]:
{101: '23.4244 31.5356',
 102: '45.009 14.2424',
 103: '35.3444 19.4242',
 104: '42.0 18.0002'}

In [1122]: df2.replace(mapping)
Out[1122]:
           SITE_ID            FIRST        SECOND  THIRD
0  23.4244 31.5356   45.009 14.2424  42.0 18.0002    NaN
1   45.009 14.2424  35.3444 19.4242           NaN    NaN
2  35.3444 19.4242     42.0 18.0002           NaN    NaN
3     42.0 18.0002              NaN           NaN    NaN
```